# How to use Regular expression and Intersect function to separate keywords from a file

Tags: c#, file, console-application

I want to read two files one is `.c` file and another is `.csv` file. Now the `.csv` has a list of C keywords. I want to match these C keywords with the `.c` program and select only keywords and display on console.

Maybe this one is simple task but I am not getting it.

With below code I am able the get all letters in char array but now this is one string how to match them with the specific words and select only that words from the string. Is there any other way.

```
class FileReader
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] cprglines = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\cprogram\\cpro\\fact.c");
        string[] ckeywordslines = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\ckeywords.csv");

        string letters = string.Empty;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (string a in cprglines)
        {
           foreach (char c in a)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetter(c))
                {
                    letters += c;
                }
            }

            list.Add(letters);
        }

        string[] arr = list.ToArray();

        foreach (string a1 in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a1);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear about what you are trying to achieve, could you please be more clear? about the requirements, and also what is the expected output

Comment: What you want is read the file and read the all the words that match to some specific words. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes. Suppose my program is having this statement void main() so I just want void and main

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Its very simple to understand. I want to match contents of two file(file1 and file1) and pick only the matched words. But my problem is  file1 is having words like this #include <stdio.h> and file2 is having keywords include, stdio. So now I want to read file1 match with file2 n display only include and stdio on console. How to separate symbols from words.

Comment: Read the .c file as a single large string, [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) it into array of words. Then you can use [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) to determine if they are C keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly. This might do the trick for you

```
string contentinc = @"#include <stdio.h> int main() {     int number;     printf('Enter an integer: ');     scanf('%d', &number);    // True if the number is perfectly divisible by 2    if(number % 2 == 0)        printf('%d is even.', number);    else        printf('%d is odd.', number);    return 0;}";
string contectincsv = "include, main, number, there are, some thing, scanf, true";
contentinc = Regex.Replace(contentinc, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+", " ");
List<string> listofc = contentinc.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
List<string> listofcsv = contectincsv.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
List<string> Commonlist = listofcsv.Intersect(listofc).ToList();
```

Comment: Intersect implicitly only return distinct elements though, so for example printf will only show up once in CommonList. This may or may not be what OP wants

Comment: Dude u r genius. This code perfectly worked and output is exact what I wanted. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: You understood what output I wanted. Above all were busy in giving me minus points and telling my post is duplicate and voting for closing this question. Sometime we are not able to explain exactly what is going on in head.

Comment: Yup!! @SurabhiPandey I agree to you that sometimes we dont know the exact terminology or Name of the technical jargons. but we are looking for some solution. But Let me tell you one of the easy way to convey the message is tell your inputs and expected output. Which makes a lot easier for programmers to understand. Hope u agree with me.

Comment: yeah I'll keep it in my mind. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here

```
foreach (string a in cprglines)
        {
           foreach (char c in a)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetter(c))
                {
                    letters += c;
                }
            }

            list.Add(letters);
        }
```

I'm not writing the code here, as it takes too much time. But I'll tell you how to write it.

1. Split the string and get individual words
2. Check for each word `()`,`#`,`;`,`-`,`+`,`/` or `%`.  If so, remove those special characters.
3. Now check whether that's there in C keyword list.
4. If it's there, then add it to your list.

Comment: Splitting the string to get individual words require one to define the delimiting characters. If the characters are defined as space and other symbols, step 1 & 2 can be done in one call.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me.